# How to/is it possible to create a SQL query that can grab 12 columns/rows of monthly data using only timestamps?

Tags: sql, sql-server

First off, I did not create this database. The table I'm querying does not separate entries into a year-month fashion. It just gets entries dumped into it and each entry has a timestamp.

I'm trying to collect data for the different processes that are logged into this database table for an Excel spreadsheet and then used for presenting purposes.

This is my query currently that I'm using to grab the first 3 months of 2022.

```
(SELECT
    COUNT(id) AS Process_1
        FROM QueueItems
            WHERE CreationTime >= CONVERT(datetime, '2022-01-01') 
            AND CreationTime < CONVERT(datetime, '2022-02-01') 
            AND QueueId = 3)
UNION
(SELECT 
    COUNT(id) AS Process_1
        FROM QueueItems
            WHERE CreationTime >= CONVERT(datetime, '2022-02-01') 
            AND CreationTime < CONVERT(datetime, '2022-03-01') 
            AND QueueId = 3)
UNION
(SELECT 
    COUNT(id) AS Process_1
        FROM QueueItems
            WHERE CreationTime >= CONVERT(datetime, '2022-03-01') 
            AND CreationTime < CONVERT(datetime, '2022-04-01') 
            AND QueueId = 3)
```

My issue is that I need the returned query to present the info in the same ordering every time January -> February -> March -> etc.

If I query this today, March is going to be the first row because obviously no processes have ran in March yet and I believe the default ordering is by ascending order. But I can't simply include an "ORDER BY month" at the end of the query because the database does not store which month each entry occurred in...

SQL is definitely not my strongest language so I apologize in advance if this is a bad question, I'm just trying to deal with this assignment that was pushed to me as quickly as possible.

Comment: `COUNT(id)` probably doesn't do what you think it does. It only counts the number of non-null values. It does not count unique instances of `id`, for that you need `COUNT(DISTINCT id)`

Comment: I didn't do a good enough job at specifying exactly what this query is doing, but COUNT(id) is doing what I want it to here. The table is constantly collecting many different processes that are ran, each one have a unique identifier (QueueId). I am trying to count how of each process occurred during a given month. I think because there is no "month" column, it doesn't matter which column I'm querying in this instance.

Comment: Then why count any column, just do `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. This will prevent the `UNION` from trying to sort the data as it believes it should. Then you can put each query in the position you want it to be in the results. I.E. January first, then February, etc...

For example...

```
(SELECT
    COUNT(id) AS Process_1
        FROM QueueItems
            WHERE CreationTime >= CONVERT(datetime, '2022-01-01') 
            AND CreationTime < CONVERT(datetime, '2022-02-01') 
            AND QueueId = 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 
    COUNT(id) AS Process_1
        FROM QueueItems
            WHERE CreationTime >= CONVERT(datetime, '2022-02-01') 
            AND CreationTime < CONVERT(datetime, '2022-03-01') 
            AND QueueId = 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 
    COUNT(id) AS Process_1
        FROM QueueItems
            WHERE CreationTime >= CONVERT(datetime, '2022-03-01') 
            AND CreationTime < CONVERT(datetime, '2022-04-01') 
            AND QueueId = 3)
```

Similarly, you could simplify your query like this...

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(month,CreationTime) AS [Month],
    COUNT(id) AS Process_1
FROM QueueItems
WHERE CreationTime >= '2022-01-01'
    AND CreationTime < '2023-01-01'
    AND QueueId = 3
GROUP BY DATEPART(month,CreationTime)
ORDER BY [Month]
```

Comment: You can order by columns not included in the query, so consider ordering by DATEPART(month,CreationTime) without including the column in the results if returning the column would be a problem.  And I really like the group by.

Comment: You are correct. Just didn't figure the data would be as self-explanatory without it. I'll let the OP decide if they want to keep it.

Comment: UNION ALL is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for pointing me in that direction. I also try incorporating your advice to clean up my query to make it look better.